# Initializing UIScrollView inside UIView displays warning: 'Local declaration hids instance variable'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

On the line below (`myScrollView.delegate = self;`) is a warning: `Local declaration of 'myScrollView' hides instance variable`. My question is, why is this happening?

**myViewController.h**

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIScrollView *myScrollView;
}
```

**myViewController.m**

```
UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
myScrollView.delegate = self; // Warning: Local declaration of 'myScrollView' hides instance variable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You local variable has the same name as the instance variable. Change the first line of your myViewController.m to:

```
myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

and you shouldn't get an error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you declared a local variable with the same name as an instance variable. As long as the local variable is in scope, assignments to the `myScrollView` variable assign to the local, not to the instance variable. In fact, it looks like your intention was to assign the instance variable `myScrollView`, not a local. In this case, you need to remove the type in front of the variable name.

This is only a warning, not an error. The compiler tells you that this area of the code may be confusing to the readers of your code (and to you after enough time passes since the moment that you wrote your code). It is a good idea to rename the local variable for better readability of your code.